# jQuery validator does not trigger before I hit enter or submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to implement jQuery Validation Plugin v1.19.2 (http://jqueryvalidation.org/), it doesn't trigger automatically at first. It only activates **afterI** I hit enter or submit the form. Once I have hit enter or submit form then it works on keyup.

Please see following gif to understand what I mean. The first field (title) is required, as you can see that I enter text there, and then delete a few times but it does not show any error. But after I submit, then each time it shows error.

Here's the **JSFiddle** link: http://jsfiddle.net/ubwq95e8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form#signup").validate({
        
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true                
            },
            
        },            
      
    });

});
```

[image]

Comment: There are countless validation plugins for jQuery, which one are you using? Maybe that's how the plug-in is supposed to work?

Comment: Sorrry, i updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't validate on onkeyup event by default, you need to implement it as per your requirements. Here's a simple example:

```
$("form#signup").validate({
         onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            $(element).valid(); 
        },
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true                
            },
            
        },
        
       errorPlacement: function(error, element){}
    });
```

Similarly for other event like onclick, onfocus* etc

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `onkeyup` in `$("form#signup").validate`.

See document: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup

```js
onkeyup: function(element) {
   $(element).valid(); 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a custom event for check inputs when focusout

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form#signup").validate({
        
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true                
            },
            
        },
        
       errorPlacement: function(error, element){}
    });
    $('#signup input').focusout(function(){
        var form = $( "#signup" );
        form.valid()
    })

});
```

here is new jsfiddle with codes that work for your case
http://jsfiddle.net/qhsj84en/